# Автоматическое построении линии между "маркерами по щелчку"

Tags: python, folium

Всем привет!

В документации  есть функция  "маркер по щелчку":

```
 m = folium.Map(location=[46.8527, -121.7649], tiles="Stamen Terrain", zoom_start=13)
    folium.Marker([46.8354, -121.7325], popup="Camp Muir").add_to(m)
    m.add_child(folium.ClickForMarker(popup="Waypoint"))
    m
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А возможно создавать линии между маркерами? Чтоб после проставления маркера к нему автоматически строилась линия, и получилось вот такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну соедините ваши маркеры через `ColorLine`, не совсем понятно, в чём вопрос.

Comment: Если маркеры ставить с помощью кода, то вопросов нет как их соединить с помощью ColorLine. А тут получается, что карта интерактивная и меркеры ставятся мышкой, и координаты в ноутбуке не отображаются. Как понимаю возможно нужно делать какую то функцию на отслеживание изменений на карте, а тут для меня уже неизвестность.

https://github.com/Bohram/Python/blob/main/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9.ipynb